# Why does helm install namespace command create the new namespace but deletes the previously created one?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am working to create dynamic namespaces using helm. However, I am experiencing a problem where when I create a new namespace with my commands, the previous namespace I created with that command is terminated and the new one is spun up.

For example, there is an existing namespace int he cluster called `original-namespace` and I want to create a new namespace called `my-new-namespace`. I have created a Makefile with the commands for simplicity where I run:

```
CHART_DIR ?= "./charts" 
NAMESPACE ?= "original-namespace" 

namespace: 
  helm install --dry-run namespace ${CHART_DIR}/namespace --set name=${NAMESPACE} > namespace.yaml
  helm upgrade --install namespace ${CHART_DIR}/namespace --set name=${NAMESPACE}
```

To execute namespace creation I simply run:
`NAMESPACE=my-new-namespace make namespace`

When this is ran the namespace `my-new-namespace` is created and  `original-namespace` is terminated. This is also vice-versa when I run the command again with:

`NAMESPACE=original-namespace make namespace`

`my-new-namespace` is removed and `original-namespace` is created again.

I have double checked my --dry-run output and everything is looking how it should. I believe it could be something with the helm upgrade --install` command but my knowledge of namespace creation is a bit limited. Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Helm keeps some information about what it has installed, and the Helm release object is itself in a namespace.  You don't use a `helm --namespace` option, so these releases go into the `default` namespace (or whatever your local Kubernetes configuration defines as the default namespace).

However, your setup is using a fixed name for the Helm release.  When you `helm upgrade` the release with a new namespace name, whatever old resources were managed by the chart are removed and replaced with the new resources.  If you want to keep both sets of resources around, you need to use either a different release name or a different namespace.  It sounds like your chart is creating the Kubernetes Namespace object, so the releases probably need to be in a different namespace.

Given a namespace name, I might run

```bash
helm install "namespace-$NAMESPACE" ./charts/namespace --set-string "name=$NAMESPACE"
```

If you do use Make here, consider generating a YAML (or JSON) values file, rather than using the sometimes problematic `--set` syntax.

```makefile
.PHONY: namespace
namespace: .helm-$(NAMESPACE)

values-$(NAMESPACE).yaml:
        echo "name: $(NAMESPACE)" >$@

.helm-$(NAMESPACE): values-$(NAMESPACE).yaml ./charts/namespace/templates/namespace.yaml
        helm upgrade --install namespace-$(NAMESPACE) \
                ./charts/namespace \
                -f values-$(NAMESPACE).yaml
        touch $@
```